# Qt vs C# - List and Vector

Tags: qt, vector, append, addrange, qvector

I want to ask the following question:

Q: What is the difference between AddRange() in C# and Append() in Qt?

I read the description for both and in my opinion they are almost identical in there  functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, the two methods are identical, though `QList` offers an override that just takes one element ( `QList::add(const T&)` ) whereas `IList` in .NET provides a method with a different name to accomplish this ( `IList.Add` ).

`QList` also offers a `push_back` method, which does exactly what the `add(const T&)` method does.